# FacebookSDK and Bolts conflicting each other (duplicate symbols) on build

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, bolts-framework

Not sure what is the problem.. 91 symbols found duplicated for armv7

Am on a Swift project targeting iOS 7.1.

Both frameworks are of the **latest versions**.

Tried cleaning project and removing derived data., but to no avail.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._URL in:
    /Users/rynecheow/Development/THPopQuiz/Frameworks/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
    /Users/rynecheow/Development/THPopQuiz/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._appStoreId in:
    /Users/rynecheow/Development/THPopQuiz/Frameworks/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
    /Users/rynecheow/Development/THPopQuiz/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._appName in:
    /Users/rynecheow/Development/THPopQuiz/Frameworks/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
    /Users/rynecheow/Development/THPopQuiz/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Had the same issue.

- **Removing the Bolts.framework was NOT a solution** since I get the errors that [*Leo Flaherty*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840546/facebooksdk-and-bolts-conflicting-each-other-duplicate-symbols-on-build#answer-25887814) mentioned (comment in the accepted answer).
- Using the solution mentioned by [*iOS_DEV*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840546/facebooksdk-and-bolts-conflicting-each-other-duplicate-symbols-on-build#answer-29171636) seems like an **ugly hack** to me.
- **Using the latest Parse and Facebook SDKs was also NOT a solution** (mentioned by [*Simon Bøgh*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840546/facebooksdk-and-bolts-conflicting-each-other-duplicate-symbols-on-build#answer-29268645)) since I was using the version 3.x of the Facebook SDK and the latest is 4.x. 
  The [Facebook SDK Change log](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x/) mentions: ***The Facebook SDK for iOS v4.0 is a major version upgrade.***
  Since I needed to meet a deadline, I couldn't dedicate time on re-writing all my Facebook code, to fit with the new 4.x SDK version.

### Solution that I propose:

Instead of adding the Bolts.framework and FacebookSDK.framework as framework to your project, add them as **Pods**:

```
pod 'Bolts'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '3.23.1'
```

Find [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/Facebook-iOS-SDK) all the Facebook SDK versions available, in case you need to use one which is not the latest.
In case you're using Swift, you need to add the following in your bridging header:
`#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
 #import <Bolts/Bolts.h>`

Comment: This solution was effective for my project with a slightly earlier Facebook iOS SDK version of 3.19. It is of note that I chose to forgo adding either framework to my Podfile. This reduced my short term risk, though I intend to migrate these into CocoaPods later.

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve the issue with Carthage? @Alex

Answer (score 51):

I had the same issue with the 91 duplicates. What worked for me was simply to remove the Bolts.framework which seems to be somehow already included in Facebook new SDK.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks! Related: you happen to be using Parse, Parse automatically #include's the Facebook SDK, so you don't need to reference both Parse+Facebook in your bridging file.

Comment: Yep, Bolts framework is redundant if using the Facebook SDK in your project.

Comment: I have the same issue however I am trying to use AWS SDK and Facebook and it seems they are conflicting again :( any ideas?

Comment: I've tried that but now I'm getting "symbol not defined" errors.

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException", referenced from:
      ___53+[PFObject(Private) deleteAllAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke214 in Parse(PFObject.o)
      ___65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke311 in Parse(PFObject.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I have same issue as Leo Flaherty. Any ideas?

Comment: I removed the Bolts.framework because of the duplicate symbols but how to use the classes of Bolts.framework now? They don't seem to be included in the FacebookSDK.framework

Comment: I have the same problem as @LeoFlaherty as well. Anyone solved this ?

Comment: @Leo Flaherty - To get rid of that error, you can go to your AppDelegate.m file and write this line after your imports: 
NSString *const BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException = @"BFMultipleExceptionsException";

Comment: OMG! @AndreiBouariu thank you so much dude. I've been trying to get rid of that error for hours! That works!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

1) I deleted the Bolts.framework that came with parse.

2) Added only parse (selecting copy into destination folder) & facebookSDK (unchecking copy into destination folder). Also checked Framework search path in Build Settings.

3) Added `NSString *const BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException = @"BFMultipleExceptionsException";`

in AppDelegate.m before

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I know an answer has already been accepted, **but this has now been resolved by Facebook**.

If you download the **latest Parse SDK (1.7.0)** and **Facebook SDK (4.0.0)** as of this writing, it should work just fine. Both SDKs were updated just hours ago.

I have imported and copied Bolts.framework and Parse.framework from the Parse SDK, and then linked to Facebooks SDK (now called FBSDKCoreKit.framework), and it successfully builds the project.

Duplicate question: [Parse and facebook sdk -duplicate symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526949/parse-and-facebook-sdk-duplicate-symbol/29268598#29268598)

Comment: I'm using Parse SDK (1.7.1) and Facebook SDK (4.0.1) and I've got the same issue back with 92 duplicate symbols showing up.  The problem is between Bolts.framework and FacebookSDK.framework.  I'm not sure why I'm having this problem.  I've removed references to both frameworks and then brought them both back in.  Cleaned the project and it still won't build.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: UPDATE! I'm using xcode 7 Beta 2 with parse 1.7.5 and facebook 4.2.0. The problem still persists.

Comment: I'm using only latest FBSDK (version i don't know but name on zip file is 20150910) though getting 197 duplicate symbols error

Answer (score -1):

Follow these step:
applicatonTarget-> Build Phase-> expend Compile sources.

Here, you need to remove those file that causes duplicate symbol error. Then build again.
[image]

Comment: This isn't the problem I guess. I've triple checked this =/

Comment: Is BFAppLinkTarget.m shows in Compile Sources section?

Comment: It looks as though you have the source file included directly into your project as well as having a link to the library. You should choose one or the other (probably the library).