# Parse and facebook sdk -duplicate symbol

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, parse-platform, bolts-framework

I have parse, facebook, bolts frameworks in my project but I get this error and I don't know how to solve it.

I tried to remove framworks and add them again.

I'm using xcode 6 and parse library 1.6.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFMeasurementEvent in:
    /Users/home/Desktop/The Live TV V2/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/home/Desktop/The Live TV V2/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
ld: 91 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation
```

Any idea?

Comment: remove bolts.framework & run may be it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Facebook and Parse Framework at the same time will cause a multiple duplicate symbol. No idea why this happens also. Removing `Bolts.framework` from Parse will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I too, was searching for same, Not sure, why no body reply, but I fixed this issue by removing Bolts.framework completely from my Project, look like many of dependencies are already included in NEW Facebook SDK.,

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I removed Bolts from my project and didn't work. Then I figured out that I had to **remove all the references** and Add Bolts again. Finally that worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know an answer has already been accepted, **but this has now been resolved by Facebook**.

If you download the **latest Parse SDK (1.7.0)** and **Facebook SDK (4.0.0)** as of this writing, it should work just fine. Both SDKs were updated just hours ago.

I have imported and copied Bolts.framework and Parse.framework from the Parse SDK, and then linked to Facebooks SDK (now called FBSDKCoreKit.framework), and it successfully builds the project.

Comment: Hi Simon, for me the solution you proposed did not work. I managed to solve it eventually by importing the Bolts framework from the Parse SDK without copying it to the project. I provided a more detailed step-by-step answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898999/parse-api-1-6-4-cannot-build-project/30841825#30841825

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises the way Bolts and FaceBookSDK is added to the project. Remove both and re-add them with copy items if needed unchecked and Create Groups selected. I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this situations work for you or not but it did work in my case.
Remove all the frameworks you have added into you project and import latest Facebook SDK and Bolts using CocoaPods.
and remove all the dependencies of bolts you have added manually.
For Example in my case.
I have just commented this line and every thing works just fine.

```
NSString *const BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException = @"BFMultipleExceptionsException";
```

Hope This Works for you as well.