# Parse+Facebook Duplicate symbols issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, ios8, facebook-sdk-4.0

Am using parse 1.8.5 and FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910(Latest) when i Build the Application am getting Duplicate symbols issue .i removed Bolts framework which was given by parse and  added below code in Appdelegate method but am facing Duplicate issue can any one guide me to fix this.

```
NSString *const BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException = @"BFMultipleExceptionsException";
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Follow this link ->

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526949/parse-and-facebook-sdk-duplicate-symbol

Comment: I fallowed that link but it is not useful for parse 1.8.5

Comment: Which symbols are getting duplicated? Are these Bolts? Is any of your project/other dependencies using their own Bolts?

Comment: @MaciekCzarnik: In Facebook Corekit and Facebook Login kit am getting Duplicate.