# Getting Error on compiling project with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

**I have followed all the steps specified https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/native/existing and also tried to add Parse Framework from cocoPods but still getting these following duplicate symbol errors, the IOS min version is 7.0 and objective c is used.**
**The errors are:**

```
duplicate symbol _BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException in:
    /Users/sabaanwar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project1-bybalqattilbrydhswfphyvovcre/Build/Intermediates/Project1.build/Debug-iphoneos/Project1.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    /Users/sabaanwar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project1-bybalqattilbrydhswfphyvovcre/Build/Intermediates/Project1.build/Debug-iphoneos/Project1.build/Objects-normal/arm64/BaseNetworkModel.o
duplicate symbol _BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException in:
    /Users/sabaanwar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project1-bybalqattilbrydhswfphyvovcre/Build/Intermediates/Project1.build/Debug-iphoneos/Project1.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
.
.
.
ld: 161 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: you run in iPhone 6 or 6+ --> 161 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64, actual error is _BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException---> this is  override in 2 times in your project please check once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29724276/4841900
The reason was Bolts and FacebookSDK were conflicting each other so i was getting duplicate symbol errors.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to compile the same code twice. This is throwing you an error and may have been caused by you installing the library and also the cocoaPods file. Another possible reason would be that you have same class implementation into two different files. However, I wouldn't expect that with a third party library. 
In order to fix that, the easiest way would probably to just delete the project ans start with a clean one. If that isn't possible, delete the cocoaPod, delete the framework and any files that you installed, clean the cache and build the project. It should compile without any problem. Then just install the SDK once.

Hope that helps, Julian

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried by deleting the cocoapod and the framework,  clean and build the code then installed the framework once by following (https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/native/existing) but the problem is still there