# Error: duplicate symbol _BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, bolts-framework

Here I have an error as shown below:

[image]

This seems to be duplicate symbols caused by **FacebookSDK** and **Bolts** conflicting each other on build. I have tried to remove Bolts framework but it caused other issues. Also I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840546/facebooksdk-and-bolts-conflicting-each-other-duplicate-symbols-on-build) but it seems to settle with adding those frameworks as Pods which I don't want to.

Here below is a list of frameworks that I think it might be relevant to this error:

- FacebookSDK.framework
- Bolts.framework
- Parse.framework
- ParseFacebookUtils.framework
- ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework
- ParseUI.framework

I've been trying to look for a right combination of those frameworks(versions) that won't cause duplication symbols error. If anyone know about this, please help me out.

Comment: The error reports says the duplicate symbol is in `Bolts.framework > BFTask` and `PAWAppDelegate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a comment from @vadian that brought me to look into my PAWAppDelegate.m and I found that after I comment out this line:

`NSString *const BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException = @"BFMultipleExceptionsException";`

the error disappears.